# Energy of flight styles (birds)

Tags: flight

What does take more energy (for a bird): to dive or gliding? My teacher thinks that gliding takes more energy, but I'm not sure about this: when a bird glides, it doesn't do anything (pretty much). But diving is stress, which takes much energy. Or am I wrong?
(edit: I don't mean the "going under the water" diving, but "nose dives")

Comment: How is diving stressful? The bird is just letting gravity do its thing.

Comment: Imagine: you're a bird flying towards the ground, getting faster and faster... not stressful? @MattDMo

Comment: No, not at all. Birds are not people. They have wings and are perfectly capable of controlling their descent.

Comment: But gliding souds much more like chilling, doesn't it?

Comment: For people like me ^^ ;-)

Comment: And you (as a bird) have to stop after that and fly up again... If you glide, you don't have to.

Comment: Google: (bird flight energy expenditure gliding) gives e.g. [*The Energetic cost of short flights in birds*](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/jexbio/203/10/1561.full.pdf), [*Heart rate and estimated energy expenditure of flapping and gliding in black-browed albatrosses*](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/216/16/3175), [*Efficiency of Lift Production in Flapping and Gliding Flight of Swifts*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0090170) and ... [cnd->]

Comment: [...cnd:] [*Energy Expenditure and Metabolic Changes of Free-Flying Migrating Northern Bald Ibis*](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0134433). This might be a start.

Comment: @fileunderwater this articles are very detailed. But Strg+F gives no results for "dive", only for "glide", means that the article has nothing about diving. But it's a good beginning, thx.